# Can't write log entry with Google Cloud's Log4net integration

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to get the Log4Net integration working in a .NET Core app that will be deployed to the AppEngine Flexible environment. My starting point is the sample code in the [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Logging.Log4Net/index.html). My code looks as such:

```
using log4net; // resolve Log4net
using log4net.Config; // resolve XmlConfigurator
using System.IO; // resolve FileInfo
using System.Reflection; // resolve Assembly

namespace Test
{
    public class PlayWithStackdriverLog4net
    {
        public void Write()
        {
            log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging = true; // enable Log4net debugging
            var xmlConfiguration = XmlConfigurator.Configure(LogManager.GetRepository(typeof(PlayWithStackdriverLog4net).Assembly), new FileInfo("log4net.xml"));
            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            log.Info("An exciting log entry!");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the end result is that I don't see *An exciting log entry!* in my Google Cloud Console's Logging pane. What am I doing wrong?

Some remarks:

1) The file, log4net.xml, is pretty much the one in the [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Logging.Log4Net/index.html), except that I've replaced PROJECT-ID with my own ID.

2) The Log4net debug output suggests that it has succesfully read from log4net.xml:

```
log4net: log4net assembly [log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a]. (.NET Framework [.NET Core 4.6.26020.03] on Microsoft Windows 6.1.7601 S)
log4net: defaultRepositoryType [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository for assembly [Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
log4net: Assembly [Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] Loaded From [Not supported on .NET Core]
log4net: Assembly [Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
log4net: Assembly [Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository [log4net-default-repository] using type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using file [log4net.xml]
log4net: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using stream
log4net: loading XML configuration
log4net: Configuring Repository [log4net-default-repository]
log4net: Configuration update mode [Merge].
log4net: Logger [root] Level string is [ALL].
log4net: Logger [root] level set to [name="ALL",value=-2147483648].
log4net: Loading Appender [CloudLogger] type: [Google.Cloud.Logging.Log4Net.GoogleStackdriverAppender,Google.Cloud.Logging.Log4Net]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message]
log4net: Converter [timestamp] Option [] Format [min=4,max=2147483647,leftAlign=True]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [thread] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [] ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [level] Option [] Format [min=5,max=2147483647,leftAlign=True]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [logger] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [ndc] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ - ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.PatternLayout]
log4net: Setting Property [ProjectId] to String value [my-project-id-goes-here]
log4net: Setting Property [LogId] to String value [mySampleLog]
log4net: Created Appender [CloudLogger]
log4net: Adding appender named [CloudLogger] to logger [root].
log4net: Hierarchy Threshold []
```

3) If I follow the example for [Stackdriver Logging Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries) which uses  Google.Cloud.Logging.V2 instead then I can find my 'hello world' text in the global resource type as expected.

Comment: I see this line in your log4net debug output: log4net: Setting Property [ProjectId] to String value [my-project-id-goes-here]  Did you redact the log, or is that the real project name?

Comment: I reported a bug here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/1926

Comment: Sorry, yes, it is redacted. And your experience looks very similar to mine.

Comment: According to the [last comment I see in GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/1926#issuecomment-369684528) it looks like there is indeed an issue with the Log4Net library, and it will be solved soon. Can you post an answer to this question stating this so that the community sees this issue is already being taken care of? Thanks!

Comment: Hi dsesto, thanks for referring to the last comment. I'll keep myself updated on that thread then.

Comment: No problem! Just make sure to accept your own answer so that the community sees this issue is being handled :) (Also it looks like some work is being done already, as there are [some new commits](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/1926#ref-pullrequest-302317223) to the library code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested by [dsesto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4482491/dsesto) I am closing this question as it has been confirmed as a bug, see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962850/cant-write-log-entry-with-google-clouds-log4net-integration?noredirect=1#comment85218912_48962850).